# Difficult Recurrence Problem

Tags: recurrence-relations

Find all integers $n\geq 3$ for which there exist real numbers $a_{1}, a_{2},...,a_{n+2}$ satisfying $a_{n+1}=a_{1}$ , $a_{n+2}=a_{2}$ and:

$a_{i}a_{i+1}+1=a_{i+2}$

for $i=1,2,..,n$

Comment: These olympiad problems can be really hard, but what have you tried?

Comment: There is a similar sequence in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2508376/interesting-recursive-sequence-a-n1-fraca-na-n-11-a-n-a-n-1), the trick that is used there doesn't seems to works here but maybe could bring some inspiration about how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Solving backwards we have for

$$
\begin{cases}
n=2\to \{2,-1,-1,2\}\\
n=5\to \{2,-1,-1,2,\frac 12,-1,2\}\\
n=8\to \{2,-1,-1,2,\frac 12,-1,2,\frac 12,-1,2\}\\
\vdots\\
n=2+3k\to \{2,-1,\underbrace{-1,2,\frac 12}_{k},-1,2\}
\end{cases}
$$

NOTE

The real solutions arise from

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 a_1&=&\frac{a_2-1}{a_1} \\
 a_2&=&1-\frac{a_1}{a_2-1} \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

the other possibilities

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
 a_1=1-\frac{a_1}{a_2-1} \\
 a_2=\frac{a_1}{a_1-a_2+1} \\
\end{array}
\right.
\ \ \text{and}\ \ \left\{
\begin{array}{c}
 a_1=\frac{a_1}{a_1-a_2+1} \\
 a_2=\frac{a_2-1}{a_1} \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

have no real solutions.