# Closed form of a recurrence relationship

Tags: recurrence-relations

So in my discrete mathematics course, we  were working on recurrence relationships, and we mostly worked with basic ones that I was able to solve.

But the next day, my professor gave the class a challenge problem that no one solved, and I am curious to the solution.

Basically, we had to find the closed form for the characteristic equation, $$a_n = \frac{a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}}{1 + a_{n-1} a_{n-2}}$$

Can someone help me find the closed form?

Comment: See if you can borrow an idea from [Interesting recursive sequence: $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_{n}+a_{n-1}}{1-a_n a_{n-1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2508376/interesting-recursive-sequence-a-n1-fraca-na-n-11-a-n-a-n-1).

Comment: Ok I think I got it now

Comment: Then you should post it as an answer